# How to get list of mail addresses from Google Calendar shares?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I want to send an email to all people whom I've shared a Google Calendar with but fail to find a method that returns me a list of email addresses in the [Calendar Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_calendar). Hints?

BTW, the source of the GDocs and script is also [available](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Alwfpys1YRkcdDN6My1BaFRzVVZLQi11LXA2cGNRR0E).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the CalenderApp service doesn't expose the list of users that it has been shared with, but it's a great candidate for a feature request.